# Drawing a line after forming 2d array in python using pygame or any other tool

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, pygame

I am creating a game using python and pygame. Firstly, I tried to create the game the using pygame.draw tool but then i realize that its hard to call points and train data set using this approach.the code for my first try is

```
import pygame
import sys

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT= 600

#define colour
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (121,202,255)
yellow= (255,255,0)


def lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect ):
    """ Get the list of points where the line and rect
        intersect,  The result may be zero, one or two points.

        BUG: This function fails when the line and the side
             of the rectangle overlap """

    def linesAreParallel( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return True if the given lines (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) and
            (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) are parallel """
        return (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)) == 0)

    def intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
        """ Return the point where the lines through (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
            and (x3,y3)-(x4,y4) cross.  This may not be on-screen  """
        #Use determinant method, as per
        #Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
        Px = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(x3 - x4)) - ((x1-x2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        Py = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(y3 - y4)) - ((y1-y2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
        return Px,Py

    ### Begin the intersection tests
    result = []
    line_x1, line_y1, line_x2, line_y2 = line   # split into components
    pos_x, pos_y, width, height = rect

    ### Convert the rectangle into 4 lines
    rect_lines = [ ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y ), ( pos_x, pos_y+height, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ),  # top & bottom
                   ( pos_x, pos_y, pos_x, pos_y+height ), ( pos_x+width, pos_y, pos_x+width, pos_y+height ) ] # left & right

    ### intersect each rect-side with the line
    for r in rect_lines:
        rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 = r
        if ( not linesAreParallel( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 ) ):    # not parallel
            pX, pY = intersectionPoint( line_x1,line_y1, line_x2,line_y2, rx1,ry1, rx2,ry2 )  # so intersecting somewhere
            # Lines intersect, but is it on-screen?
            if ( pX >= 0 and pY >= 0 and pX < WINDOW_WIDTH and pY < WINDOW_HEIGHT ):          # yes! on-screen
                result.append( ( round(pX), round(pY) ) )                                     # keep it
                if ( len( result ) == 2 ):
                    break   # Once we've found 2 intersection points, that's it

    return result



#opening window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

#pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (200,100,250,250), 2)
#pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (150,75,350,300), 2)
#pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (100,50,450,350), 2)
##draw lines
##upper line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,50),(325,100),3)
##lower line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(325,350),(325,400),3)
##left line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(100,200),(200,200),3)
##right line
#pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(450,200),(550,200),3)
#@kingsley correction of the code
board_rects = [  ( 200,100,250,250, red ), ( 150,75,350,300, green ), ( 100,50,450,350, red ) ]
for rect in board_rects:
    x_pos, y_pos  = rect[0], rect[1]
    width, height = rect[2], rect[3]
    colour        = rect[4]
    pygame.draw.rect( screen, colour, ( x_pos, y_pos, width, height ), 2 )

board_lines = [ ( 325,50,325,100 ), ( 325,350,325,400 ), ( 100,200,200,200 ), ( 450,200,550,200 ) ]
for line in board_lines:
    line_from = ( line[0], line[1] )
    line_to   = ( line[2], line[3] )
    pygame.draw.line( screen, white, line_from, line_to, 3)    

for line in board_lines:
    for rect in board_rects:
        rect = rect[ 0: -1 ] # trim off the colour
        intersection_points = lineRectIntersectionPoints( line, rect )
        for p in intersection_points:
            pygame.draw.circle( screen, blue, p, 10 )  # Draw a circle at the intersection point

#updating window
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

after that i tried to use the 2d array for creation of board. In this i want to draw line on specific high lighted boxes only and i want to remove/delete all other boxes. i used the following code:

```
import pygame
 
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20
MARGIN = 5
#set the array
grid = []
for row in range(19): 
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(19):
        grid[row].append(0)
# Set row 1, cell 5 to one. (Remember rows and
# column numbers start at zero.)
grid[0][0] = 1


pygame.init()
 
# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = [600, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
 #set the tittle of the game
pygame.display.set_caption("My Array Game")
 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
 
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
#while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            # Set that location to one
            grid[row][column] = 1
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

 
    # --- Game logic should go here
 
    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here
 
    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
 
    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(BLACK)
 
    # --- Drawing code should go here
     # Draw the grid
    for row in range(19):
        for column in range(19):
            color = WHITE
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = GREEN
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])

 
    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
 
    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)
 
# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

the boxes which i want to retain

[image]

i want to draw lins on the selected boxes

[image]

coords of the boxes

[image]

Comment: I want to get the exact location of the points/boxes so that i can reference them later. I just needed the highlighted boxes but i am unable to find a way to create them as i am new to the programming and coding.

Comment: Can you please point out how can i do that?

Comment: Probably I've misunderstood your question. Your code works fine. What do you want to to achieve? Do you need someone who computes the coordinates for you?

Comment: i just want to keep the highlighted boxes and want to remove/hide/inaccessible all other boxes and also to draw a line as indicated in picture. i have found a way to draw line on these points now i just want to remove/del/hide other boxes.

Comment: You cannot delete boxes, just do not draw them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "delete" boxes which are drawn on the display surface, don't draw them:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for row in range(19):
        for column in range(19):
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = GREEN
                box_rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                            (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                            WIDTH,
                            HEIGHT]
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, box_rect)
```

---

TO d raw the lines, you've to find the center of the box. Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object to find the center point of a box. The center point of the box with the index (`row`, `column`) can be computed by:

```py
box_rect = pygame.Rect((MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                       (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                       WIDTH,
                       HEIGHT)
box_center = box_rect.center
```

Comment: then the entire grid will be gone and with that the highlighted boxes will not appear.

Comment: but yes you give me an idea let me check it first.......

Comment: @shyckh @shyckh Why? I thought the green box are indicated by `grid[row][column] == 1` (as seen in the image)?